# How do I override “Mage_Customer_Model_Group” in Magento 1.4.1.1?

Tags: overrides, magento-1.4

How do I override “Mage_Customer_Model_Group” in Magento 1.4.1.1 ?

I've made a new module named `Lpf_ModulePendingApproval`. This module contains a class named "Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Group".
This class only defines a new customer group. I heard that modifying `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Group.php` is not the right way...

I'd like new modules being able to use this new class.

Could you tell me how I should configure `Lpf_ModulePendingApproval.xml`, `Group.php` and `config.xml`.

There are my files.

Group.php

```
class Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Group extends Mage_Customer_Model_Group
{
    const PENDIND_APPROVAL_ID       = 4;
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <session>Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Group</session>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Lpf_ModulePendingApproval.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lpf_ModulePendingApproval>
    </modules>
</config>
```

AccountController.php

```
<?php

//include_once "Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php";
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php');
class Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //Mage::log(__METHOD__ . 'surcharge urlBeforeLoginSuccess ');
        parent::indexAction();
    }

    /**
     * Customer logout action
     */
    public function logoutPendingApprovalAction()
    {
        $this->_getSession()->logout()->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl());
    }

    # surcharge de _loginPostRedirect
    /**
     * Define target URL and redirect customer after logging in
     */
    protected function _loginPostRedirect()
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
        $urlBeforeLoginSuccess = $session->getData("urlBeforeLoginSuccess");
        $session = $this->_getSession();

        if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl() ) {

            // Set default URL to redirect customer to
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());

            // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
            if ($session->isLoggedIn())
            {
                if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard')) {
                    if ($referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME)) {
                        $referer = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer);
                        if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if ($session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
                }
            } else {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
            }
        } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
        }
        else {
            if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                //Removed $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
                $session->setAfterAuthUrl($urlBeforeLoginSuccess);
            }
            if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
            }
        }

        $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        if($groupId==Mage_Customer_Model_Group::PENDIND_APPROVAL_ID)
        /*{ 
            // Pending Approval Process
            $this->logoutPendingApprovalAction();
            $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
             Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->__('Your account needs to be approved by our team...'));
        }
        else
        {*/
            $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a factory system:

`Mage::getModel('beforeSlash/afterSlash')`, where `beforeSlash` is called namespace or module and `afterSlash` class.

What you want to do is:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <beforeSlash>
            <rewrite>
                <afterSlash>Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Group</afterSlash>
            </rewrite>
        </beforeSlash>
    </models>
</global>
```

So in your case:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <customer>
            <rewrite>
                <group>Lpf_ModulePendingApproval_Model_Group</group>
            </rewrite>
        </customer>
    </models>
</global>
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems not to be working. The new constant is not found, so kraches the website. This might come from my configuration files.

Comment: please update your question and add new informations. what do you mean by crash? if you don't have more informations, please read http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: I'm using the new constante in a class nammed "AccountController" located in a new module nammed "Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin" I had created.
The wesite crashes on line 67 ===> if($groupId==Mage_Customer_Model_Group::PENDIND_APPROVAL_ID)   <==          from "AccountController.php". When I comment that line, the wesite doesn't crash.